# How could I solve this Reaction-Diffusion PDE using mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, numerics

I'm modeling a problem with PDEs, So I gotta solve numerically this Reaction-Diffusion Partial Differential Equation

$$
\frac{\partial u(t,x,y)}{\partial t}=D\Big( \frac{\partial^{2}u(t,x,y)
}{\partial x^{2}} +\frac{\partial^{2}u(t,x,y)
}{\partial y^{2}}\Big)+r\ u(t,x,y) \,\, ,
$$
where $D$ is the diffusion coeficient and the $r$ is a reaction coefficient (both constants). My boundary conditions are:

$$
\frac{\partial u(t,0,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u(t,x,0)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial u(t,a,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u(t,x,b)}{\partial y}=0 \,\, ,
$$

and my inicial condition is:

$$
u(0,x,y)=u_{0}\delta (x) \,\, ,
$$

Where $\delta (x)$ is the Dirac Delta Function. I'm not able to solve this equation on mathematica yet, How could I solve this equation numerically? (I'm not very sure about the boundary conditions, if there's something worong with them, feel free to tell me.)

The code I've tried to make is this:

It defines the EDP I'm dealing.

```
eqd = D[u[t, x, y], t] == 
D[u[t, x, y], x, x] + D[u[t, x, y], y, y] + u[t, x, y]
```

It defines the domain of my problem.

```
\[CapitalOmega] = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 100 && 0 <= y <= 100, {x, y}];
```

So I've tried to solve this using NDSolve, where I've changed the Dirac Delta by the constant function 100 as inicial condition, and the boundary conditions I tried to express as functions D[u[t,0,y],x]==0 and so on,  this way:

```
NDSolve[{eqd, D[u[t, x, y], x]/.x->0 == 0, D[u[t, x, y], x]/.x->100 == 0, 
D[u[t, x, y], y]/.y->0 == 0, D[u[t, x, y], y]/.y->100 == 0, 
u[t, x, y] == 100}, u, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

What has produced the following message:

```
"Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first \
argument {\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\"u\", TagBox[
RowBox[{\"(\", 
RowBox[{\"1\", \",\", \"0\", \",\", \"0\"}], \")\"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None][t, x, y] == u[t, x, y] + \
\*SuperscriptBox[\"u\", TagBox[
RowBox[{\"(\", 
RowBox[{\"0\", \",\", \"0\", \",\", \"2\"}], \")\"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None][t, x, y] + \*SuperscriptBox[\"u\", TagBox[
RowBox[{\"(\", 
RowBox[{\"0\", \",\", \"2\", \",\", \"0\"}], \")\"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None][t, x, \
y]\),True,True,True,True,u[0,x,y]==100}"
```

and didn't give me an answer for my problem...

Thank you for supporting!

Comment: Take a look at `NDSolve` and `NeumannValue`.

Comment: @Rahul I'm Using mathematica 9, this way I don't have the NeumannValue feature avaliable to me...

Comment: `NeumannValue` is convenient but not necessary to solve this system of equations.  To obtain more thorough responses, post your equations in Mathematica format.

Comment: Note that the solution to this equation will grow exponentially at rate r once the initial distribution spreads out over the domain.

Comment: @bbgodfrey This is exactly my question, what's the better way to solve this equation for those initial/boundary conditions? What's the more suitable? I think that the NDSolve would be a great choice, but when I make my evaluations the results look awkward, so I don't know if I'm using inadequate boundary conditions, or the method used to do the evaluation isn't the better one.

Comment: Try `D[u[t, x, y], x] /. x -> 0` or equivalently  `Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, 0, y]`, etc.  I'm sure you already have realized that `D[u[t, 0, y], x]`, on the other hand, does not work.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yes, I've realized that it doesn't work, So I'm trying your way! :D

Comment: @bbgodfrey When I tried your suggestion, mathematica still answer me that my inicial/boudary conditions are inconsistent.... Do you think that I didn't set the boundary conditions in a suitable way?

Comment: Did `NDSolve` produce an answer anyway?  (Usually, it does for this warning message.)  If so, does it look reasonable?  To say more, I need to see the code you are using.  Please add it to your question.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I'm unable to make and code, I've edited the question with my code, take a look!

Comment: @WaynerKlën  I'm glad to see that Eric Towers has answered your question.  Good luck.

Comment: @bbgodfrey thanks! Your suggestions helped me a lot by the way!

Comment: Just wanted to point out the OP's code doesn't work because expressions like `/.x->0 == 0` evaluate to `/.x->True` etc, and the initial condition was wrongly specified as `u[t, x, y] == 100` instead of `u[0, x, y] == 100`. Fixing the latter, and using parentheses to fix replacements, e.g. `(D[u[t, x, y], x]/.x->0) == 0` gives a solution equivalent to the one in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I note that your diffusion constant has gone away (been set to $1$).  I get working solutions with

```
soln = NDSolve[{
  D[u[t, x, y], t] == 
    D[u[t, x, y], x, x] + D[u[t, x, y], y, y] + u[t, x, y], 
  Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, 0, y] == 0,
  Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, 100, y] == 0,
  Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][t, x, 0] == 0,
  Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][t, x, 100] == 0,
  u[0, x, y] == 100
}, u, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}, {t, 0, 10}]

Plot3D[u[t, x, 1] /. soln, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 100}]
```

Is there any particular analysis you're interested in?

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! :D Actually There's one, I would like to solve this problem with the inicial condition $u(0,x,y)==u_{0}\delta (x)$, what I can't express in mathematica language.

Comment: @WaynerKlën : How is this different from the line `u[0,x,y] == 100` (with whatever appropriate constant instead of "`100`")?

Comment: The function $\delta(x)$ is a Dirac delta function, what expresses $u_{0}$ animals in a defined place from domain, consequently it changes the distribution of animals with the time along the domain, I guess.

Comment: @WaynerKlën : The strict purpose of using the delta function in a boundary (or initial) condition is to correct for units.  We can only ever integrate densities, so to turn a number into a density we must multiply it by a function that has vanishing support (place where it is nonzero) but finite integral.  The Dirac delta function does this.  However, once we abstractualize away from units, we no longer need that device -- we directly specify that the value of $u$, a density, is its initial value and need not use the device of delta to correct units.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, this way, you've answered my question fully!  Thank you very much for your supporting!

Comment: could I see the solution function produced by the interpolating approximation?

Comment: You can...  But it may be less informative you you expect.  The result is an `InterpolatingFunction[]`, which is essentially a large array of values at points and a little data on the order of interpolation to use between them.  `soln /. u // FullForm` will show you more, though you may have to tell your front end to "show more" a few times so it doesn't just hide the table of data.

Comment: I doubt this comment will be answered, but your initial conditions actually do not match the OP's. Your initial condition has a uniform concentration everywhere. Therefore, we will have the same thing happening at all points in space over all time here (the diffusion is essentially pointless). The OP wanted initial concentration just starting at the $x = 0$ plane, which would then diffuse (and react) into the space.

Comment: @AaronStevens : I see OP wrote "`u[0, x, y] == 100`", then edited to "`u[t, x, y] == 100`".  The current version is clearly wrong.  The variant you are describing would be "`u[0,0,y] == 100`".